# TeXShop inverse search highlight color

Tags: highlighting, texshop, forward-inverse-search

[EDIT 18 Jan 2015: This has now been fixed in 3.49! Thanks to Richard Koch and company. Copied from http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/version.html:

Three hidden preferences were added, allowing users to change the yellow highlight color to another color, when used by inverse sync from the pdf window to the source text. This is helpful if the user has changed the default colors of the source window. The new items are

defaults write TeXShop ReverseSyncRed 1.00

defaults write TeXShop ReverseSyncGreen 1.00

defaults write TeXShop ReverseSyncBlue 0.00

]

Inverse search in TeXShop, invoked by pressing the command key and clicking on the Preview window, jumps to the corresponding source. This is a great feature, but the text that I jump to is highlighted in a yellow color that is very difficult to see. Further, until I click in the source code window, any text I select (e.g. with shift + arrow keys) is also highlighted in the same hard-to-see color, as opposed to my system standard for highlighting (purple). This happens even though the focus is on the source window.

This seems to be a built in feature of TeXShop, with no corresponding preference. Is there any way to set the highlight color?

I'm on TeXShop 3.48.1, OSX 10.10.1.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I'm surprised this has not improved. I had this problem years ago.

Comment: Actually I did read the guide. Sorry, but I can't figure out what is wrong with my question. There isn't really a MWE. Maybe the preview text is not optimal?

Comment: I wasn't asking you for an MWE. That is just a standard 'new user' greeting message. (There's a different one if an MWE is missing but needed.) The non-standard part starts 'I'm surprised...' which was just a comment.

Comment: Ah, the non-standard part confused me. (Thanks for doing this in general, it is a noble service.)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think this is possible to change. There are various hidden preferences that can be changed, (see Hidden Preference Items in the How do I Configure TeXShop part of the TeXShop help panel) but this is not one of them.